# Plugin for customer group

Tags: customer, plugin, group

if set "Privileged Customers" group for a customer, than ablity to add vouchers for this customer. Otherwise exception should be thrown with the next message "Customer isn't in a privileged group".
Model

```
public function createVoucherStatus($status)
    {
        $voucherStatus = $this->voucherStatusModelFactory->create();
        $voucherStatus->setStatusCode($status);
        try {
            $this->voucherStatusResourceFactory->save($voucherStatus);
            $response = ['idVoucherStatusCode' => ($voucherStatus->getId())];
            return json_encode($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Status has code already");

        }
    }
```

Plugin

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Voucher\Plugin;

use Exception;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory as CustomerModelFactory;
use Vendor\Voucher\Model\VoucherManagement as Subject;

class PrivilegedCustomer
{

    /**@var CustomerModelFactory */
    private $customerModelFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerModelFactory $customerModelFactory
     */

    public function __construct(CustomerModelFactory $customerModelFactory)
    {
        $this->customerModelFactory = $customerModelFactory;
    }

    public function aroundcreateVoucher(Subject $subject, $id, $callback)
    {
        $customerGroupId = $this->customerModelFactory->create()->load($id)->getGroupId();

        if ($customerGroupId = 4) {
            $callback();
        }
        throw new Exception("Customer isn't in a privileged group");

    }
}
```

But it giving back "message": "Plugin class Vendor\Voucher\Plugin\PrivilegedCustomers doesn't exist". I've  got red eyes already to reading manuals,but didn't fin solution